# gnuplot versing 5.2.2 become unresponsive when trying to input inline data both with using pseudofile method with "-" pusdofile name and using $ sign

Tags: gnuplot, inline

I'm trying to learn gnuplot from a book and, up to now, I have encuntered a problem which I don't know where else to ask for help.

I tried to use the following command:

```
$data << EOD
1 0.5
2 0.75
3 0.99
EOD
```

If everything is OK, I should be able to input the two data columns as shown in the interactive gnuplot session. However, after pressing enter after the EOD indicator, the gnuplot session become unresponsive but the cursor's still blinking. I couldn't input any data from this point on.

Another method of using inline data to plot is to use pseudofile name "-" in the using directive. Unfortunately, I can't get this to work either.

To obtain the exact same plotting result as the code above using this method, I should input the following command:

```
plot "-" u 1:2
```

After pressing enter, I got the following response:

```
input data ('e' ends)>
```

The cursor's blinking but gnuplot wasn't responsive and I couldn't input any data beyond that point.

I tried to search in the bug section and there's nothing about this problem either. I'd appreciate any solution for this. Since this is my first post, I'd also appreciate any suggestion should there be anything improper about this post. Thank you very much.

**My gnuplot version is 5.2.2 patch level 2 running on Windows 10, terminal type is wxt 0 enhanced. The installation file is gp522-win64-mingw.exe and was downloaded from** https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/gnuplot/5.2.2/

**Additional info:** I have no problem plotting graphs from functions and actual data files.